# I would like to know if my approach of creating this UI is improper

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

[image]

I would like to create the UI as seen in this picture. My approach involves using multiple card views. I am uncertain as to if this is the right way to go about doing this. This method seems a bit laborious, and repetitive, secondly I am not sure if this will cause any problems in the future such as memory problem etc. For the experienced developers please enlighten me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Controller.RegisterActivity">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/messageToolBar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backArrow"
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="30dp"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:text="Profile"
                android:textColor="#424242" />


        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/userInfoConstraint"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="6:4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/messageToolBar">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/profileImageView"
                        android:layout_width="90dp"
                        android:layout_height="90dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                        app:civ_border_color="#FFFFFF"
                        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/nameTv"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:textColor="#424242"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/album_title"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profileImageView"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/profileImageView"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/profileImageView" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="Yale"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/nameTv"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/nameTv"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/nameTv" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="4:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/userInfoConstraint"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/userInfoConstraint"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/userInfoConstraint">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Empl ID"
                        android:textColor="#424242"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView7"
                        android:layout_width="64dp"
                        android:layout_height="16dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:text="2335795"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView6"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView6"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView6" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="6:4"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/constraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout">

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView8"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:text="Contact"
                        android:textColor="#424242"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.05"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/emailTv"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView2"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView8"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView8" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/emailTv"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/emailTv"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pencil" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                        android:text="333-333-1121"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/emailTv"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/emailTv" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
                        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/pencil" />


                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: At first you don't need to put each CardView in a ConstraintLayout. The other things are ok in my view. Also, if the number of CardViews is dynamic and their content are same, I suggest that you use a RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple set background for your ConstraintLayout so you don't need to create CardView within ConstraintLayout

If you want shadow in you ConstraintLayout use, To show shadow in ConstraintLayout you must add background to it, simply set #FFFFFF and use this

```
    android:elevation="4dp"
```

Or you can create a custom background to have round corners and custom background colors

Hope this will help